# How to fix the 404 error after deploy on Vercel?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vercel

I developed an application on Vue.js and hosted it on a certain host, however, I'm having problems with my site's routes. Using vue-router, I set the following route:

`{ path: "/certificate/public/:id", name: "PubliCert", component: PublicCertificate,},`

However, when I try to access this already hosted route, it returns to me:

> 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: gru1::ljchp-1708045045658-70bb89f93e2f

When I run the same process on localhost, everything works perfectly, however, when I deployed the application this error started. How can I fix this problem so that the route is accessible?

I want to make it so that when accessing the /certificate/public/43 route, I can access the desired route.

Answer (score 0):

Check Hosting Configuration

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/myapp/',
  routes: [
    { path: '/certificate/public/:id', name: 'PubliCert', component: PublicCertificate }
    // other routes
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**